# Subtype Check with Type DAG

Tags: graphs, type-theory, python, c++

Trying to understand how compiler/static-type-checker checks for subtyping, I run into 2 problems.

### 1. Reachability in DAG

Since both Python/C++ support multiple inheriatnce, the types can be represented as a DAG.

```
A  C
| / \
B    D
|\   |
E F /
|  x
| / \
G    H
```

Now `is_subtype(A,B) -> bool` becomes the problem of reachability query in the DAG.

For a single query, this will take O(n). For multiple queries, I found a 2-hop transitive closure paper, where `reachability(a,b)` operation can be done with `first_edge(a,b)` which takes `|L_{out}(a)| + |L_{in}(b)|`. Since the size of graph with added transitive closures is up to `O(n^1.5)`, This is in average `O(n^0.5)`, however `O(n)` in the worst case.

### 2. Generic Parameter

To check `is_subtype(Sequence[String], Iterable[Any])`, there can be 2 paths:

1. `Sequence[String]` to `Sequence[Any]` (covariant) to `Iterable[Any]`
2. `Sequence[String]` to `Iterable[String]` to `Iterable[Any]`

I don't know where to start if I have  to augment the DAG in 1 with Parameters. Instantiating types and considering `Sequence[String]` as one node seems wasteful and uses too much cpu/memory.

### Questions

Q1. How do current compiler/checks solve this problem?
Is brute-force enough for sparse graphs in practical usages?

```
Parent* ptr = new Child();  // gcc

b: List
a: Iterable = b  # mypy, pyright
```

Reading mypy code https://github.com/python/mypy/blob/master/mypy/subtypes.py ,
this is brute-force recursive check in my understanding.

Q2. What's good algo for reachability check in sparse DAG?

Q3. Is there a better representation of problem than this DAG? How does it work with type parameters?

Q4. Given `let a = b;` (Rust), `auto a = b;` (C++) or `a = b` (Python), Should I assume type(a)==type(b) for Rust/C++ and type(a)>=type(b) for Python? (Python allows `a: Iterable = Sequence`) How does type-bound check mix with type-interence? I guess I use equalities+unification for type-inference and a list of inequality constraints for type-bound checks.

Considering that clangd / pyright provides LSP these days, I am interested in both batch processing / incremental update.